# Run a postgresql command with ansible playbook. Postgresql requires password

Tags: database, postgresql, ansible

I would like to write an Ansible playbook which tries to handle some postgresql command. I did earlier a similar playbook, but in that case Postgresql didn't need password.

I thought I could use my old playbook, which works fine, but I was wrong. This database requires password. I know that Ansible has postgresql support which is fine (postgresql_db, postgresql_ext, postgresql_lang, postgresql_privs, postgresql_user) and with them I can do half of the work and it handles password just fine, BUT I can't figure out how to send a simple sql commands to my database. In my old playbook I used "shell" command to send those requests (eg: `shell: "psql {{ databases.name }} --username {{ admin_user}} -c 'DROP SCHEMA public CASCADE;'"`).

And also I would like to upload a db_dump. Earlier I used psql for this, but this new database requires password...

Can someone give me tips how to handle this situation? I'm using ansible 2.0 and the database can be reached only from a specific remote host.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Create a `.pgpass` file at a non-default location as part of your playbook, and put the password there. Specify its location in the `PGPASSFILE` environment variable. Delete it once it's no longer needed.

See [libpq environment variables](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/libpq-envars.html).

Alternately I think you can use a connection string to connect and specify the password as part of the connection string, e.g.

```
 'dbname=mydb user=fred password=borkbork'
```

(untested)

Comment: @kilimandzsaro Note that command lines can be visible to other users in the system via `ps` etc so be careful if using passwords in connection strings.

Comment: Thanks for the note, I'm trying the .pgpass solution and it seems to work for my case.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a new role that provides four new modules:

- postgresql_table: ensure that a table is present (or absent) in database
- postgresql_row: ensure that a row is present (or absent) in a table
- postgresql_query: execute an arbitrary query in database and return results
- postgresql_command: execute an arbitrary query in database

Look here for docs: https://github.com/rtshome/ansible_pgsql

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following module in Ansible
https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/postgresql_query_module.html

For example:

```
- name: Select query to db acme with positional arguments and non-default credentials
  postgresql_query:
    db: acme
    login_user: django
    login_password: mysecretpass
    query: SELECT * FROM acme WHERE id = %s AND story = %s
    positional_args:
    - 1
    - test
```